# Is it possible for the Unity video player to play a video from Android internal storage? If yes, how?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, import, video-player, android-storage

Please help me find a way to **get a video from the android internal storage during run time** and play it using the video player component attached to an object, in Unity.

I want to access the video from the internal storage during run time and not from the assets.

Comment: can u tried for this ??

Comment: Whether I've tried doing this? I tried setting the file location as the url, but, that is not working.

Comment: past your tried code

Comment: Play from  StreamingAssets folder. See duplicate for more information

Comment: `vid.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().url = "file://storage/emulated/0/Video.mp4";`   But i don't think we can access files outside the build like this.

Comment: @Programmer : That'd only allow me to play a video within the StreamingAssets folder, right? What if i need to play it from a storage location that i can pick?

Comment: @Programmer could you remove the duplicate tag, as it is not?

Comment: @Programmer: I need to able to take a video from a folder in the android internal storage(Not added during build), say from sdcard/Videos and then pull it on to an object. Would that be possible? I'm new to Unity.

Comment: Title says Internal Storage. SDCard is not an internal storage.....

Comment: If this is not longer a duplicate then you need to explain why it is different

Comment: I was just giving an example of a random storage location. My question is how to get a video or any file from such a location.

Comment: @NewAlexandria I do not want to keep a file in streaming Assets and then use it from the phone's storage.  Instead i want my game object to be able play a video picked from any location in the internal storage.

Comment: Also, is the StreamingAssets folder accessible through a file explorer in android?

Comment: Well, IMHO this is not a duplicate. The proposed alternative ("Using new Unity VideoPlayer and VideoClip API to play video") does not mention playing from internal storage at all.